# adding information to pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have this data

```
line_tab<-                

    elements   scaffold  start    end Lengths        A           B        C        D                      E                     F                 G                  
  BovB_1297  KQ417326.1    763   2186    1423 0.1565491 0.02291220 1.9857781  1.4346243          2.81754891            1.23339700         1.0394839
  BovB_3317  KQ416600.1 660334 661626    1292 0.0000000 0.02523534 0.0000000  0.1934799          0.11710299            0.06318396         0.0000000
  BovB_5130  KQ418760.1 327212 328873    1661 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0265819  0.0000000          0.02277198            0.03686048         0.0000000
  BovB_6215  KQ417629.1 339534 340586    1052 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.8394018  1.2277020          0.43145549            0.34919346         0.2685752
  BovB_9578  KQ420742.1 157232 158657    1425 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000  0.0000000          0.02654334            1.00251877         0.0000000
  BovB_9976  KQ423592.1  30989  32425    1436 0.0000000 0.02270478 0.4612034  0.3191430          0.13170009            0.24160383         0.1388863
```

then I've created an heatmap using `pheatmap`, with this code

```
  pheatmap(log10(line_tab+1), color = col.pal.red, 
           fontsize = 8, cluster_cols = FALSE, cluster_rows= FALSE, cellwidth = 15, cellheight = 5, 
           fontsize_row = 5, main = "LINEs length")
```

but I would to add more information to my heatmap. 
I'm trying to add a legend located near each row that is showing the column "Length" for each "element".
could you suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add the labels to each row of the heat-map. Then you may use the argument `labels_row` of `pheatmap()`:

```
library(pheatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

pheatmap(log10(line_tab[, -(1:2)] + 1), 
    color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 7, name ="Oranges")))(100),
    fontsize = 8, cluster_cols = FALSE, cluster_rows= FALSE, 
    cellwidth = 15, cellheight = 5, 
    fontsize_row = 5, main = "LINEs length",
    labels_row = line_tab$Lengths, 
    filename = "heat_map.png", heigh = 1.75, width = 2.8)
```

[image]

Let me know please whether this is what do you need to obtain.

Note please that `pheatmap(log10(line_tab+1),...)` won't work because `pheatmap()` requires a numerical matrix. That is why I had to exclude first two columns.